# How can I make Emacs TRAMP offer completions from my ~/.ssh/config?

Tags: emacs, sftp, autocomplete, tramp

When I want to access remote files over sftp in Emacs using TRAMP, I would like Emacs to offer me completions from the hostnames in my ssh config. How can I do this?

For example, if I have two hosts in my ssh config, "alpha" and "bravo", when I type `/sftp:a` at the find-file prompt, it should complete "alpha".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remote access is documented in the [Tramp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/). You want the section on [customizing completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Customizing-Completion). Put something like this in your `~/.emacs`:

```
(setq my-tramp-ssh-completions
      '((tramp-parse-sconfig "~/.ssh/config")
        (tramp-parse-shosts "~/.ssh/known_hosts")))
(mapc (lambda (method)
        (tramp-set-completion-function method my-tramp-ssh-completions))
      '("fcp" "rsync" "scp" "scpc" "scpx" "sftp" "ssh"))
```

Comment: Close enough. I just had to replace `"ssh"` with `"sftp"`. Actually, I set it for both.

Comment: Oh, wow. There are a lot of ssh-based methods, aren't there? I don't even know what half of those are.